# Error when creating Kinesis Delivery Streams with OpenSearch

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kinesis

I created an OpenSearch domain using Terraform with the OpenSearch_2.3 engine. I also managed to create Kinesis data streams without any issues but when I want to add a delivery stream I need to configure `elasticsearch_configuration` for the delivery stream as I want to send data to OpenSearch. But I get an error so I am not sure what I am doing wrong, is something wrong with the `aws_opensearch_domain` resource or is it Kinesis related?

```
resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "domain" {
  domain_name    = "test"
  engine_version = "OpenSearch_2.3"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "r4.large.search"
  }

  tags = {
    Domain = "TestDomain"
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_kinesis_stream" "stream" {
  name             = "terraform-kinesis-test"
  shard_count      = 1
  retention_period = 48

  stream_mode_details {
    stream_mode = "PROVISIONED"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "delivery_stream" {
  name        = "terraform-kinesis-firehose-delivery-stream"
  destination = "elasticsearch"

  s3_configuration {
    role_arn           = aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn         = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
    buffer_size        = 10
    buffer_interval    = 400
    compression_format = "GZIP"
  }

  elasticsearch_configuration {
    domain_arn = aws_opensearch_domain.domain.arn
    role_arn   = aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn
    index_name = "test"
    type_name  = "test"

    processing_configuration {
      enabled = "true"

      processors {
        type = "Lambda"

        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "LambdaArn"
          parameter_value = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_processor.arn}:$LATEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error: `` elasticsearch domain `my-domain-arn` has an unsupported version: OpenSearch_2.3 `` How is it not supported? [Supported Versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/what-is.html#choosing-version)

I am new to Kinesis and OpenSearch, pardon my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks ago, I had a similar problem as I thought 2.3 was supported. However, Kinesis Firehose actually does not support OpenSearch_2.3 (yet). I downgraded to `OpenSearch_1.3` and it worked as expected. You can find more information in the upgrade guide.

[Supported Upgrade Paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/version-migration.html#supported-upgrade-paths)

```
resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "domain" {
  domain_name    = "test"
  engine_version = "OpenSearch_1.3"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "r4.large.search"
  }

  tags = {
    Domain = "TestDomain"
  }
}
```