# Unable to find Terraform aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream details for feeding data to Opensearch Serverless

Tags: terraform, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Looking to feed data from aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream to OpenSearch Serverless.

opensearch_configuration {

Unknown for Open Search Serverless.

}

opensearch_configuration {
domain_arn =

}

Is OSS too new for Hashicorp AWS Module for Kinesis?

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74834132/error-when-creating-kinesis-delivery-streams-with-opensearch might be a version issues as explained here.